# C#/C++ - how to get size of directory where path is too long, or permission denied?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

There are loads of questions and answers about how to get the size of a directory - recursively summing the length of the files - easy.

However all the answers I've seen are incomplete. Where you recursively iterate over a volume there are directories that throw exceptions - `UnauthorizedAccessException` for example. I've also noticed in Win 7 there are paths that exceed 260 characters, which throws a `PathTooLongException`.

All of which means, in C# at least, you cannot scan a C:\ drive and get a real figure back for the size of the volume because you have to skip any directory or file that throws an exception.

I am looking for a way of getting a proper, true, accurate figure for bytes stored on disk for a given directory. I don't care if I have to go low level and write some C++, or call the Win APIs.

How can this be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size of a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015341/size-of-a-directory)

Comment: it isn't a duplicate - the linked question again doesn't address the issues you encounter, rather it just has another recursive algorithm.

Comment: But the answers say that there isn't an API to call. That's important!

Comment: About long pathes, have you seen this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx

Comment: Do you need the total size in a volume/disk or specifically the size of a directory?

Comment: log0 - specifically the size of the directory

Comment: Bo Persson - so it isn't possible and let's close the question? if everyone had that attitude we wouldn't have any answers.

Comment: Flot2011 - no i hadn't many thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

Is not going to be easy but it can be done and while I am not sure that you can overcome the permissions issues essentially what you have to do is go on a lower level and read the NTFS master file table directly as shown in this wonderful [piece of code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CCS-LABS-C-Accessing-the-d317805c/sourcecode?fileId=60931&pathId=14261056) shared by [this caring developer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CCS-LABS-C-Accessing-the-d317805c) who got the idea from another such developer.

Here is [a reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that will help you. Google 'NTFS architecture' or design for more specs.
And please share some of your work & research:) It will be helpful to many

**Edit**:
[Another project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81456/An-NTFS-Parser-Lib) which may help you. After testing it says that it supports only NTFS 3.0 or higher.

Comment: That looks promising, thanks for the info, I will give it a try. (Bo Persson take note :))