# How can I find the size of all files located inside a folder?

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems, directory

Is there any API in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) for getting the size of a specified folder?

If not, how can I get the total size of a folder including all subfolders and files?

Comment: Size of folder? Or size of all files, located in the folder? And which OS?

Comment: ya I meant size of all files in the folder.And the OS is windows

Comment: You'll need a library, for example [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

Comment: Almost same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015341/size-of-a-directory)

Comment: @Daniel Frey. Actually I don't want to use any third party library. Just want to implement in pure c++.Any way thanks for the info.

Comment: @Cyrille I saw that one, but just want to know if a single api can do that for me.

Comment: Are you using MSVC++ ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Actually I don't want to use any third party library. Just want to
>   implement in pure c++.

If you use MSVC++ you have [`<filesystem>` "as standard C++".](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694.aspx) 
But using boost or MSVC - both are "pure C++".

If you don’t want to use boost, and only the C++ std:: library this answer is somewhat close. As you can see [**here, there is a Filesystem Library Proposal (Revision 4)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3505.html). Here you can read:

> The Boost version of the library has been in widespread use for ten
>   years. The Dinkumware version of the library, based on N1975
>   (equivalent to version 2 of the Boost library), ships with Microsoft
>   Visual C++ 2012.

To illustrate the use, I adapted the answer of @Nayana Adassuriya , with very minor modifications (OK, he forgot to initialize one variable, and I use `unsigned long long`, and most important was to use: `path filePath(complete (dirIte->path(), folderPath));` to restore the complete path before the call to other functions). I have tested and it work well in windows 7.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr2::sys;

void  getFoldersize(string rootFolder,unsigned long long & f_size)
{
   path folderPath(rootFolder);                      
   if (exists(folderPath))
   {
        directory_iterator end_itr;
        for (directory_iterator dirIte(rootFolder); dirIte != end_itr; ++dirIte )
        {
            path filePath(complete (dirIte->path(), folderPath));
           try{
                  if (!is_directory(dirIte->status()) )
                  {
                      f_size = f_size + file_size(filePath);                      
                  }else
                  {
                      getFoldersize(filePath,f_size);
                  }
              }catch(exception& e){  cout << e.what() << endl; }
         }
      }
    }

int main()
{
    unsigned long long  f_size=0;
    getFoldersize("C:\\Silvio",f_size);
    cout << f_size << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is complete() from ?

Comment: First: dirIte->path() is sufficient for populating the filePath properly. "complete()" is not necessarily.
Second: getFoldersize recursive call in the else body, should take filePath as a string ( can use filePath.string() if you are using experimental/filesystem v1 with C++17/20)

Answer (score 10):

How about letting OS do it for you:

```
long long int getFolderSize(string path) 
{
    // command to be executed
    std::string cmd("du -sb ");
    cmd.append(path);
    cmd.append(" | cut -f1 2>&1");

    // execute above command and get the output
    FILE *stream = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (stream) {
        const int max_size = 256;
        char readbuf[max_size];
        if (fgets(readbuf, max_size, stream) != NULL) {
            return atoll(readbuf);
        }   
        pclose(stream);            
    }           
    // return error val
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I cant give you an upvote since I dont have enough reputation. Anyway its a different approach

Comment: Well, I can: +1. Honestly, I don't understand how this work...(a link??). Also better return long long.

Comment: I am just using popen (mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/popen.3.asp) to run 'du' (disk usage) command and parsing the output returned by that. I mostly use this approach to debug code where I suspect it could be dying due to some system related issue (say doing 'stat' on file I was reading). I modified it to return long long int as you suggested.

Comment: @krimir: Not unless you install UnxUtils or MSYS or a similar package that contains `du` and `cut` as well as `bash` first, and not unless you modify it, because as it is (using pipe and output redirection), it sure won't work.

Answer (score 5):

You may use boost in this way. You can try to optimize it some deeper.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>



    using namespace std;
    namespace bsfs = boost::filesystem; 

    void  getFoldersize(string rootFolder,long & file_size){
        boost::replace_all(rootFolder, "\\\\", "\\");   
        bsfs::path folderPath(rootFolder);                      
        if (bsfs::exists(folderPath)){
            bsfs::directory_iterator end_itr;

            for (bsfs::directory_iterator dirIte(rootFolder); dirIte != end_itr; ++dirIte )
            {
                bsfs::path filePath(dirIte->path());
                try{
                    if (!bsfs::is_directory(dirIte->status()) )
                    {

                        file_size = file_size + bsfs::file_size(filePath);                      
                    }else{
                        getFoldersize(filePath.string(),file_size);
                    }
                }catch(exception& e){               
                    cout << e.what() << endl;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    int main(){
        long file_size =0;
        getFoldersize("C:\\logs",file_size);
        cout << file_size << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: +1: but you forgat to initialize file_size, and probably you need to  path filePath(complete (dirIte->path(), folderPath));

Answer (score 5):

Something like this would be better to avoid adding symbolic(soft) links:

```
std::uintmax_t directorySize(const std::filesystem::path& directory)
{
    std::uintmax_t size{ 0 };
    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(directory))
    {
        if (entry.is_regular_file() && !entry.is_symlink())
        {
            size += entry.file_size();
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: This code throws `recursive_directory_iterator::operator++: The system cannot find the path specified.` on Win 11. This article suggest adding \\?\ but it does not seem to make any difference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-file-namespaces 
There seem to be no way forcing `recursive_directory_iterator` to use Unicode either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

[Size of files in a folder](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/249201/how-to-get-size-of-all-files-in-a-directory)
Please have a look at this link

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


__int64 TransverseDirectory(string path)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    __int64 size = 0;
    string fname = path + "\\*.*";
    HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(fname.c_str(),&data);
    if(h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do {
            if( (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) )
            {
                // make sure we skip "." and "..".  Have to use strcmp here because
                // some file names can start with a dot, so just testing for the 
                // first dot is not suffient.
                if( strcmp(data.cFileName,".") != 0 &&strcmp(data.cFileName,"..") != 0)
                {
                    // We found a sub-directory, so get the files in it too
                    fname = path + "\\" + data.cFileName;
                    // recurrsion here!
                    size += TransverseDirectory(fname);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                LARGE_INTEGER sz;
                // All we want here is the file size.  Since file sizes can be larger
                // than 2 gig, the size is reported as two DWORD objects.  Below we
                // combine them to make one 64-bit integer.
                sz.LowPart = data.nFileSizeLow;
                sz.HighPart = data.nFileSizeHigh;
                size += sz.QuadPart;

            }
        }while( FindNextFile(h,&data) != 0);
        FindClose(h);

    }
    return size;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    __int64 size = 0;
    string path;
    size = TransverseDirectory("c:\\dvlp");
    cout << "\n\nDirectory Size = " << size << "\n";
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

For more detail PLease CLick [Here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/249201/how-to-get-size-of-all-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: This is not a good answer. "Extract" some of the important points from this link and write them here. You may leave the link for "more details".

Comment: @meh good point, the link might go stale and would then be of no use to subsequent users asking the same question.

Comment: Thank u all for the kind support.

Answer (score 1):

The file system functions are integral part of each operative system, written mostly in C and assembler, not C++, each C++ library implementation for this are in one way or another a wrapper of this functions. Taking on count the effort and if you will not use your implementation in different OS, maybe is a good idea to use this functions directly and save some overhead and time.

Best regards.

Comment: hmmm... there are many "wraper": MFC, .NET, Qt, etc. Are all bad?

Comment: **Not bat or wrong**, from my point of view and as I understand, C++ libraries aim to improve portability and hide complications of direct use of underlayer functions and methods offer for the operative systems (big picture). In this case the effort to read directories and summarize file sizes are not different from OS methods and C++ libraries like boost, as you can see in all examples shared in this posts.

Comment: Of course, I partialy agree with you. But partcularly learning Win32 is sometimes ...hard, and not very C++ (the Q was: a C++ API). Thank for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have my types definition file with:

```
typedef std::wstring String;
typedef std::vector<String> StringVector;
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
```

and code is:

```
uint64_t CalculateDirSize(const String &path, StringVector *errVect = NULL, uint64_t size = 0)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HANDLE sh = NULL;
    sh = FindFirstFile((path + L"\\*").c_str(), &data);

    if (sh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        //if we want, store all happened error  
        if (errVect != NULL)
            errVect ->push_back(path);
        return size;
    }

    do
    {
        // skip current and parent
        if (!IsBrowsePath(data.cFileName))
        {
            // if found object is ...
            if ((data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                // directory, then search it recursievly
                size = CalculateDirSize(path + L"\\" + data.cFileName, NULL, size);
            else
                // otherwise get object size and add it to directory size
                size += (uint64_t) (data.nFileSizeHigh * (MAXDWORD ) + data.nFileSizeLow);
        }

    } while (FindNextFile(sh, &data)); // do

    FindClose(sh);

    return size;
} 

bool IsBrowsePath(const String& path)
{
    return (path == _T(".") || path == _T(".."));
}
```

This uses UNICODE and returns failed dirs if you want that.

To call use:

```
StringVector vect;
CalculateDirSize(L"C:\\boost_1_52_0", &vect);
CalculateDirSize(L"C:\\boost_1_52_0");
```

But never pass `size`

Comment: What has to be included to get this code to work? I feel like Ive tried everthing and I still keep getting errors. Ive included windows.h and tried a bunch of other things along with it, it still doesnt work.

Comment: @hennessy you need to include `vector`, `string`, `Windows.h`. It looks like thats all, what error do you get?

Comment: Now I tried with these included: #include <windows.h> #include <string> #include <vector>  - Error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument '1' to 'void* FindFirstFileA(LPCSTR, LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA)'| - and -  error: 'IsBrowsePath' was not declared in this scope| - and -  error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::basic_string<wchar_t>' and 'CHAR [260] {aka char [260]}')| ----- I have the 3 typedefs that you made above the function in main.cpp, so its like first the includes, then typedefs, then the CalculateDirSize function and then main().

Comment: I am compiling with Code::Blocks using MinGW if that matters in this case.

Comment: Your project doesn't use UNICODE, you need either use UNICODE or use `std::string` instead of `std::wstring`

Comment: Thanks that one helped, I changed std:wstring to std::string and removed the L that was infront of the "//" at the 2 places. What about the IsBrowsePath, though, I have tried declaring it but I just cant figure out how to use it. I still keep getting this error: . \main.cpp|54|error: 'IsBrowsePath' was not declared in this scope| -- It seems to be the last problem that I cant figure out.

Answer (score 1):

```
//use FAT32   
#undef UNICODE        // to flag window deactive unicode
#include<Windows.h>  //to use windows api
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
#pragma pack(1)  //tell compiler do'nt do prag
struct BPB
{
BYTE            JMP[3];
BYTE            OEM[8];
WORD            NumberOfBytesPerSector;
BYTE            NumberOfSectorsPerCluster;
WORD            NumberOfReservedSectors;
BYTE            NumberOfFATs;
WORD            NumberOfRootEntries16;
WORD            LowNumbferOfSectors;
BYTE            MediaDescriptor;
WORD            NumberOfSectorsPerFAT16;
WORD            NumberOfSectorsPerTrack;
WORD            NumberOfHeads;
DWORD           NumberOfHiddenSectors;
DWORD           HighNumberOfSectors;

DWORD           NumberOfSectorsPerFAT32;
WORD            Flags;
WORD            FATVersionNumber;
DWORD           RootDirectoryClusterNumber;
WORD            FSInfoSector;
WORD            BackupSector;
BYTE            Reserver[12];
BYTE            BiosDrive;
BYTE            WindowsNTFlag;
BYTE            Signature;
DWORD           VolumeSerial;
BYTE            VolumeLabel[11];
BYTE            SystemID[8];
BYTE            CODE[420];
WORD            BPBSignature;
};
//-----------------------------------------------------------
struct DirectoryEntry
{
BYTE Name[11];
BYTE Attributes;
BYTE Reserved;
BYTE CreationTimeTenth;
WORD CreationTime;
WORD CreationDate;
WORD LastAccessTime;
WORD HiClusterNumber;
WORD WriteTime;
WORD WriteDate;
WORD LowClusterNumber;
DWORD FileSize;   //acual size of file
};
//---------------------------------------------------
void dirFunction(string s){
string path = "\\\\.\\" + s + ":";
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);//open partition 
BPB bootSector;//var from bootSector structure
DWORD readBytes = 0;
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    cout << "Error " << GetLastError()<<endl;
    return;
}
ReadFile(hFile, (BYTE*)&bootSector, sizeof(bootSector), &readBytes, 0);//read partition and load bootSector information inside our structure
LONG t = 0;
ULONG distance = bootSector.NumberOfReservedSectors +
    bootSector.NumberOfFATs*bootSector.NumberOfSectorsPerFAT32;//distance from begine until Root Directory or content of partetion
distance *= bootSector.NumberOfBytesPerSector;//convert distance number to bytes value

SetFilePointer(hFile, distance, &t, FILE_BEGIN);//set pointer to root directory begine or begine of data
int clusterSize = bootSector.NumberOfBytesPerSector*bootSector.NumberOfSectorsPerCluster; //cluster size 
int NumberOfEntries = clusterSize / sizeof(DirectoryEntry); //number of record inside cluster
DirectoryEntry*  root = new DirectoryEntry[NumberOfEntries];//descripe the partetion
ReadFile(hFile, (BYTE*)root, clusterSize, &readBytes, 0);
DWORD clusterNumber;
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfEntries; i++)
{
    if (root[i].Name[0] == 0)//there no entery after this
        break;
    if (root[i].Name[0] == 0xE5)
        continue;
    if ((root[i].Attributes & 0xF) == 0xF)
        continue;
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        cout << root[i].Name[j];
    if((root[i].Attributes & 0x10) != 0x10){
        cout<<".";
    for (int j = 8; j < 11; j++)
        cout << root[i].Name[j];
    }
    if ((root[i].Attributes & 0x10) == 0x10){
        cout << "\t<Folder>" ;
    }else{

        cout<<"\t<File>" ;
    }
    clusterNumber = root[i].HiClusterNumber << 16;
    clusterNumber |= root[i].LowClusterNumber;
    cout <<"\t"<<root[i].FileSize<<"bytes" << "\t" << clusterNumber<<"cluster" << endl;
}

CloseHandle(hFile);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------
string convertLowerToUpper(string f){

string temp = "";
for (int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++){

    temp += toupper(f[i]);
}

return temp;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------
string getFileName(BYTE filename[11]){
string name = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    if (filename[i] != ' ')
        name += filename[i];
    }
return (name);

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
int findEntryNumber(DirectoryEntry*  root, int NumberOfEntries, string required){
string n;
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfEntries; i++){

    if (strcmp((getFileName(root[i].Name).c_str()), convertLowerToUpper(required).c_str()) == 0){

        return i;
    }


}

return -1;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------
void typeFunction(string fileName, string s){
string path = "\\\\.\\" + s + ":";
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);//open partition 
BPB bootSector;//var from bootSector structure
DWORD readBytes = 0;
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    cout << "Error " << GetLastError()<<endl;
    return;
}
ReadFile(hFile, (BYTE*)&bootSector, sizeof(bootSector), &readBytes, 0);//read partition and load bootSector information inside our structure
LONG t = 0;
ULONG distance = bootSector.NumberOfReservedSectors +
    bootSector.NumberOfFATs*bootSector.NumberOfSectorsPerFAT32;//distance from begine until Root Directory or content of partetion
distance *= bootSector.NumberOfBytesPerSector;//convert distance number to bytes value

SetFilePointer(hFile, distance, &t, FILE_BEGIN);//set pointer to root directory begine or begine of data
int clusterSize = bootSector.NumberOfBytesPerSector*bootSector.NumberOfSectorsPerCluster; //cluster size 
int NumberOfEntries = clusterSize / sizeof(DirectoryEntry); //number of record inside cluster
DirectoryEntry*  root = new DirectoryEntry[NumberOfEntries];//descripe the partetion
ReadFile(hFile, (BYTE*)root, clusterSize, &readBytes, 0);
DWORD clusterNumber;
int index = findEntryNumber(root, NumberOfEntries, fileName);
if (index == -1){

    cout << "File is not found" << endl;
    return;
}
if (((root[index].Attributes & 0x10) == 0x10) ){

    cout << "Is not file name" << endl;
    return;
}
clusterNumber = root[index].HiClusterNumber << 16;
clusterNumber |= root[index].LowClusterNumber;
ULONG temp = (clusterNumber - 2) * clusterSize;
distance += temp;
t = 0;
SetFilePointer(hFile, distance, &t, FILE_BEGIN);
BYTE* buffer = new BYTE[clusterSize];
readBytes = 0;


    ReadFile(hFile, (BYTE*)buffer, clusterSize, &readBytes, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < root[index].FileSize; i++){

        cout << buffer[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    CloseHandle(hFile);

}
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------
void delFunction(string filename, string s){
string path = "\\\\.\\" + s + ":";
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);//open partition 
BPB bootSector;//var from bootSector structure
DWORD readBytes = 0;
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    cout << "Error " << GetLastError()<<endl;
    return;
}
ReadFile(hFile, (BYTE*)&bootSector, sizeof(bootSector), &readBytes, 0);//read partition and load bootSector information inside our structure
LONG t = 0;
ULONG distance = bootSector.NumberOfReservedSectors +
    bootSector.NumberOfFATs*bootSector.NumberOfSectorsPerFAT32;//distance from begine until Root Directory or content of partetion
distance *= bootSector.NumberOfBytesPerSector;//convert distance number to bytes value

SetFilePointer(hFile, distance, &t, FILE_BEGIN);//set pointer to root directory begine or begine of data
int clusterSize = bootSector.NumberOfBytesPerSector*bootSector.NumberOfSectorsPerCluster; //cluster size 
int NumberOfEntries = clusterSize / sizeof(DirectoryEntry); //number of record inside cluster
DirectoryEntry*  root = new DirectoryEntry[NumberOfEntries];//descripe the partetion
ReadFile(hFile, (BYTE*)root, clusterSize, &readBytes, 0);
DWORD clusterNumber;
readBytes = 0;
t = 0;
int index = findEntryNumber(root, NumberOfEntries, filename);
if (index == -1){

    cout << "FIle is not found" << endl;
    return;
}
if ((root[index].Attributes & 0x10) == 0x10){

    cout << "Is not file name" << endl;
    return;
}

//delete file
root[index].Name[0] = 0xE5;
SetFilePointer(hFile, distance, &t, FILE_BEGIN);
WriteFile(hFile, (BYTE*)root, clusterSize, &readBytes, 0);
cout<<filename<<" is deleted\n";

CloseHandle(hFile);

}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
string removeExtention(string s){

string t = "";

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){

    if (s[i] == '.')break;
    t += s[i];
}

return t;

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
void main()
{
string swich_value;
string directory;
string file_name;
//dirFunction("G");
cout<<"plz, Enter single Partition character ------> example E or G\n\n";
cin>>directory;
string path = "\\\\.\\" + directory + ":";
cout<<"current directory is "<<path<<endl;
cout<<"Enter Options: \n1- dir \n2- type file_name.extention \n3- del file_name.extention\n\n";
again:
cin>>swich_value;

if(swich_value.at(1)!='i')
    cin>>file_name;
string answer;
switch(swich_value.at(1)){  
case 'i':
    dirFunction(directory);
    cout<<"\nare  you want to do another process: y or n?";
    cin>>answer;
    if (answer.at(0)=='y')
        goto again;
    break;
case 'y':
    typeFunction(removeExtention(file_name), directory);
    cout<<"\nare  you want to do another process: y or n?";
    cin>>answer;
    if (answer.at(0)=='y')
        goto again;
    break;
case 'e':
    delFunction(removeExtention(file_name), directory);
    cout<<"\nare  you want to do another process: y or n?";
    cin>>answer;
    if (answer.at(0)=='y')
        goto again;
    break;


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **"boost::filesystem"**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

unsigned long long int get_directory_size(const fs::path& directory){
    if (!fs::exists(directory)) return 0;

    if (fs::is_directory(directory)){
        unsigned long long int ret_size = 0;
        fs::directory_iterator m_dir_itr(directory);

        for (m_dir_itr = fs::begin(m_dir_itr); m_dir_itr != fs::end(m_dir_itr); ++m_dir_itr){
            fs::directory_entry m_dir_entry = *m_dir_itr;
            if (fs::is_regular_file(m_dir_entry.path())){
                ret_size += fs::file_size(m_dir_entry.path());
            }else if (fs::is_directory(m_dir_entry.path())){
                ret_size += get_directory_size(m_dir_entry.path());
            }
        }

        return ret_size;
    } else if (fs::is_regular_file(directory)){
        return fs::file_size(directory);
    }

    return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/) {
    // Assuming 'C:/Folder' be any directory then its size can be found using
    auto folder_size = get_directory_size("C:/Folder");
    printf("Size of 'C:/Folder' is %d\n",folder_size);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

5 years and not a simple solution with standard C++, that's why I would like to contribute my solution to this question:

```
uint64_t GetDirSize(const std::string &path)
{
    uint64_t size = 0;
    for (const auto & entry : std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
    {
        if(entry.status().type() == std::experimental::filesystem::file_type::regular)
            size += std::experimental::filesystem::file_size(entry.path());
        if (entry.status().type() == std::experimental::filesystem::file_type::directory)
            size += GetDirSize(entry.path().generic_string());
    }
    return size;
}
```

Use it for example by calling
`GetDirSize("C:\\dir_name")`
if you're using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of `std::filesystem`, you no more have to use any system APIs or any external libraries.

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace n_fs = ::std::filesystem;
double archive::getFolderSize(std::string path)
{
        double r = 0.0;
        try{
           if (!n_fs::is_directory(path))
           {
                r += (double)n_fs::file_size(path);
           }
           else
           {
                for(auto entry: n_fs::directory_iterator(path))
                getFolderSize(entry.path().string());
            }
        } 
        catch(exception& e)
        { 
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl();
        }
        return r;
}

int main(){
    double folderSize = getFolderSize("~/dev/"); //Replace with your path
    std::cout << "Size of Folder: " << folderSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using GetFileSizeEx function. Following is some sample code for this. You need to get the size from the LARGE_INTEGER union though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("C:\test.txt","r");
    int fileNo = _fileno(fp);
    HANDLE cLibHandle = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fileNo);
    long int fileSize = 0;
    LARGE_INTEGER fileSizeL;
    GetFileSizeEx(cLibHandle, &fileSizeL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `GetFileSize()` works on folders/directories and the question is about getting the total size of a directory's content.  At least, as I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating a folder size in bytes on Windows.

```
size_t GetFolderSizeInBytes(std::wstring path)
{
    size_t result = 0;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
    HANDLE hFileHandle;
    std::wstring sourcePath(path);

    if (GetFileAttributes(sourcePath.c_str()) & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        sourcePath.push_back(L'\\');

    std::wstring fileName(sourcePath);
    fileName.append(L"*");

    hFileHandle = FindFirstFileEx(
            fileName.data(),
            FindExInfoStandard,
            &findData,
            FindExSearchNameMatch,
            NULL,
            FIND_FIRST_EX_ON_DISK_ENTRIES_ONLY);

    if (hFileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if (!wcscmp(findData.cFileName, L".") || !wcscmp(findData.cFileName, L".."))
                continue;

            if ((findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0)
            {
                // Folder
                std::wstring newPath = path + L"\\" + findData.cFileName;
                result += GetFolderSizeInBytes(newPath);
            }
            else
            {
                // File
                unsigned long high = findData.nFileSizeHigh;
                unsigned long low = findData.nFileSizeLow;
                size_t size = size_t(high * (MAXWORD + 1)) + low;
                result += size;
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFileHandle, &findData));

        FindClose(hFileHandle);
    }

    return result;
}
```