# How to get a folder size via Windows API

Tags: c++, windows

On Windows OS, we can use right-click on a folder, and it will show property information which will contain folder size information. Now, I want to use Windows API to get a folder size, I do not want to use FindFirstFile/FindNextFile to enumerate all files. Thanks in advance.

I tried below code, however, it returns size with an invalid data.

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(tsFolderPath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 
    NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL|FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL); 

LARGE_INTEGER fileSize; 
GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &fileSize);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Comment: You do realize that property page updates "folder size" along with enumerating contained files, don't you? So it still uses `FindFirstFile` you want to avoid. You will have to too.

Comment: What @RomanR. said is true. When you open the property page of a folder that contains thousands of files and sub-folders you will see that the folder size gets updated continuously.

Comment: @RomanR. Actually, I tried with enumerating method, however, it seems also not much consistant with OS property result on System disk, (ex. C:\) and I find that because some file with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT is a symbol link which will be counted as twice. however, after I filter it. I find the result is still not  same as OS. and there are some file attribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx) So what is the correct way? Thanks!

Comment: How is your example with CreateFile/GetFileSizeEx related to your text including the wish for FindFirstFile/FindNextFile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of answers to your question, though one is mostly a technicality.

The first would be to use `NtQueryInformationFile` (or `zwQueryInformationFile`) to collect the data. This can return information on all the files in a directory in a single call, avoiding the loop required from the normal functions. Use is somewhat tricky though -- documentation is primarily for device drivers. An application that uses it is a native application instead of Win32. Documentation for this is minimal.

The second possibility would be to write a loop, but instead of `FindFirstFile`, use `FindFirstFileEx`. This lets you specify `FindExInfoBasic` and `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` to optimize the retrieval since you don't need the `cAlternateFilename` and will be enumerating all the files in the directory, so it should read as much of the relevant data as possible at once.

Comment: For system disk, when enumerate,  the total size is not consistant with OS. I find that FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED will affect result much.

Comment: Well, yes, a reparse point has a non-trivial meaning: "this entry does is not a normal file but a reference to one". Higher-level API's respect the semantics, perform the reparse, and will return the size of the referenced file instead of the reference.

Comment: From the name of it (I have not tested) it sounds like `NtQueryDirectoryFile` and/or `NtQueryDirectoryFileEx` would be better suited for the task.

Comment: @iseiryu: That would also work, but (at least arguably) less well. Either can return a structure that gives you the allocation size and the offset of the end of each file, so they can both do the job. But the structure you get from NtQueryDirectoryFile[Ex] includes quite a bit more that you don't care about for this task. That means you get results for fewer files at a time for a given buffer size (or need a bigger buffer to hold data for a specific number of files).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no API function to directly retrieve a folder's size. You have to iterate over the contained files.

**Edit:** 
Consider similar questions on SO:

- [How to find the size of all files, located inside a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495756/how-to-find-the-size-of-all-files-located-inside-a-folder)
- [Size of a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015341/size-of-a-directory)

Comment: You can see this behaviour, too, in the folder's property dialog: the actual size will increase in the display while the files are iterated.