# How can I get a result larger than 2^32 from shl?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, bit-shift

Declaration...

```
const
  n = 2 shl 33
```

will set constant `n` to value 4 without any compiler complaint!

Also...

```
Caption := IntToStr(2 shl 33);
```

...return 4 instead 8589934592. 
It looks like the compiler calculates like this:

> 2 shl 33 = 2 shl (33 and $1F) = 4

But without any warning or overflow.

The problem remains if we declare:

```
const
  n: int64 = 2 shl 33;
```

The number in constant is still 4 instead 8589934592.

Any reasonable work around?

Comment: Why do you expect a 32 bit integer to have such a large value? It can only hold 2^32 different values.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I expect at least compiler worning!

Comment: @GJ: There is no compiler error warranted. There's no overflow. The need to cast when using `Int64` has been documented since it was first introduced (well, during the times there was documentation for Delphi <g>). I'll see if I can dig up a reference to this and update my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for the wrong results, according to both the Delphi compiler and Windows 7's calculator in programmer mode. (The answer you're wanting is actually `2 shl 32`, BTW.)

You need to cast both sides of the `shl` to `Int64`:

```
const
  n = Int64(2) shl Int64(33);
```

This produces

```
N = 17179869184;
```

The current [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types) (for XE2, but applies to earlier versions of Delphi as well) notes this in `Fundamental Integer Types`. However, that page mentions only having to cast one of the operands as `Int64`; my test shows it to require both operands be typecast in the `const` declaration above - typecasting only one (regardless of which one) also resulted in `n = 4;'.

Comment: Ok my mistake, the right result is 17179869184, but I expect at least compiler worning.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to talk to Embarcadero about the compiler warning; I have no influence over that myself. :) But since it's working as documented, I don't see where a warning would be necessary - it's documented in the link above, and has been documented since `Int64` was introduced. The exact quote from the docs: "Operations return a value of type Int64 only when performed on one or more Int64 operands.". Since neither of the operands (values on the right side of the assignment) were Int64, an Int64 was  not returned. No warning needed - working as designed and documented.

Comment: Ok, for me is the same if we declare const `n = $100000000;` or `n = 1 shl 32;` isn't it? But as I can see it is not so.. :)

Comment: You don't need to define the type of the constant as Int64 if the result of assigned value is an Int64.  In the example above, you could simply use `const n = Int64(2) shl Int64(33);`.  This will also allow `n` to behave as a true constant instead of a typed constant.

Comment: @Jerry, good point. I think I tried that after I tried typecasting one of the operands and it didn't work, and forgot to remove it. Fixed.

Comment: No, @GJ. It's not the same. The former is a single token, and the compiler can see immediately that it's bigger than a 32-bit type, so it uses Int64 for the type. The latter is three tokens, and the two numeric tokens are both assigned the Integer type because they're small enough to fit. The language definition says that `shl` applied to two Integer operands is itself an Integer, not an Int64. How is the compiler to know you wanted the bigger result when others might have wanted the (backward compatible)  smaller one using the same code?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: OK I understand, but still at constant declaration `1 shl 32` isn't equal 1 in any case. :) And here I have expected compiler worning! Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Actually, @GJ., it's equal to 1 in the case of old code, written before Delphi had 64-bit integer types. It was well defined to be 1 because the right operand was always truncated to 5 bits. To maintain backward compatibility, that behavior needs to stay the same today as it was 15 years ago, or else people's programs suddenly break.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: OK that explain everything.