# FileSize, what difference from this procedure and what is better use?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

about get size of a file, i have this two functions:

```
function GetFileSize1(const FileName: TFileName): Int64;
var
 iTmp: Int64;
 SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  iTmp := -1;
  if FindFirst(FileName, faAnyFile, SearchRec) = 0 then
  begin
    iTmp := SearchRec.Size;
    System.SysUtils.FindClose(SearchRec);
  end;
  Result := iTmp;
end;
```

And:

```
function GetFileSize2(const FileName: TFileName): Int64;
var
 FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
  try
    Result := FileStream.Size; 
  finally  
    FileStream.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

In practise, what is the difference of it? Both return same result of course but what is more affidable, more fast, more secure? Or better, what is preferible use? First or second?
Thanks very much.

Comment: See also [Getting size of a file in Delphi 2010 or later?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642220/576719).

Comment: Hello @LuRD, i use delphi xe2 and TFile.GetSize not is present; i have checked now.

Comment: This was a request from Smasher, see the answers for solutions.

Comment: @Marcello: In the post LU RD linked to, the OP, Smasher, said that he would fancy something like `TFile.GetSize`. Implicitly, one understands that that precise function cannot be present, at least not in Smasher's version of Delphi.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thanks, to begin not understood, but after yes about sense.

Answer (score 10):

Well, the obvious difference is that `GetFileSize2` opens the file, using the `CreateFile` API to obtain a file handle. In contrast, `GetFileSize1` does not because it reads the size from the file meta data.

So I would expect `GetFileSize1` to perform better. Although, for many applications that performance difference would not matter. Much more significantly, `GetFileSize2` can fail due to a sharing violation in situations that `GetFileSize1` will succeed. So you really should not use `GetFileSize2`.

Note also that the two functions you present behave differently in case of an error: `GetFileSize1` returns -1, and `GetFileSize2` raises an exception.

Personally I prefer this version:

```
function GetFileSize3(const FileName: string): Int64;
var
  fad: TWin32FileAttributeData;
begin
  if not GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(FileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @fad) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Int64Rec(Result).Lo := fad.nFileSizeLow;
  Int64Rec(Result).Hi := fad.nFileSizeHigh;
end;
```

Or, if you prefer to return -1 in case of error you would write it like this:

```
function GetFileSize3(const FileName: string): Int64;
var
  fad: TWin32FileAttributeData;
begin
  if not GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(FileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @fad) then
    exit(-1);
  Int64Rec(Result).Lo := fad.nFileSizeLow;
  Int64Rec(Result).Hi := fad.nFileSizeHigh;
end;
```

Some how this feels more natural than calling `FindFirstFile`, but that's perhaps just personal preference. There's really nothing wrong with the `FindFirstFile` approach. Although it doesn't need that `iTmp` variable. You can write it more clearly like this:

```
function GetFileSize1(const FileName: TFileName): Int64;
var
 SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(FileName, faAnyFile, SearchRec) = 0 then
  begin
    Result := SearchRec.Size;
    System.SysUtils.FindClose(SearchRec);
  end
  else
    Result := -1;
end;
```

**Update:** @CodeInChaos makes a good point about the approaches that don't open a file handle. These approaches can give inaccurate results for hard linked files.

Comment: Hello @David, this third solution raise only when file not is found then? I mean, is free-problem respect to first and second solution? Is correct?

Comment: @Marcello I don't quite understand that comment. However, I've added more to the answer to cover error handling. And note well that your two functions handle errors in different ways.

Comment: I'd guess that `GetFileSize1` needs to open a handle to the directory. I also wouldn't be surprised if it returned false information when used with hard linked files.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, that's a good point about hard links. I don't know anything about opening handles to directories.

Comment: `FindFirst` faster than a call to `CreateFile` win32 api?

Comment: Sadly, I see it all the time in Delphi codebases. I have been using something like your GetFileSize3 for some time now, and I like it. I think that's the way to go for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is, that GetFileSize1 reads the Meta Information of a file (Windows-API-Call) and GetFileSize2 has a direct touch to the file (getting FileHandle, walk through until the end to calculate the size).

So GetFileSize1 consumes less performance/ressources than GetFileSize2

UPDATE

I forgot to mention, if the file is already in use, you maybe not allowed to get access with a TFileStream, but the Meta Information will be available.

UPDATE (just another Variant of Davids suggestion)

```
function GetFileSize1(const FileName: TFileName): Int64;
var
 SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst( FileName, faAnyFile, SearchRec ) = 0 then
    try
      Exit( SearchRec.Size );
    finally
      System.SysUtils.FindClose(SearchRec);
    end;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

Comment: Personally I like the version that doesn't do FindFirst OR opening a file, the one David shows as `GetFileSize3`

Comment: @WarrenP so do i and thats why i upvoted davids answer a couple of seconds after posting :o)